# Reverse binary representation of an int (only significant bits)

Tags: c#, integer

This based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764933/reverse-binary-representation-of-int-only-significant-bits/32766487#32766487) question in [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com). The accepted answer uses `Convert.ToString(int, base)` to get the binary `string`, reverses it and converts it back to `int`. Nice trick!

I have very little experience with bit twidling (using `Flag`s is about it :p ) so I decided to try and code the solution to this problema without using `Convert`.

I came up with the following solution. I'd like to know easier ways to do this as there are probably many much better than the one I found.

```
public static IEnumerable<bool> ToBinary(this int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        yield return (n & (1 << i)) != 0;
    }
}

public static int ToInt(this IEnumerable<bool> b)
{
    var n = 0;
    var counter = 0;

    foreach (var i in b.Trim().Take(32))
    {
        n = n | (i ? 1 : 0) << counter;
        counter++
    }

    return n;
}

private static IEnumerable<bool> Trim(this IEnumerable<bool> list)
{
    bool trim = true;

    foreach (var i in list)
    {
        if (i)
        {
            trim = false;
        }

        if (!trim)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

And now you'd use it like this:

```
var reversed = n.ToBinary().Reverse().ToInt();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `while` loop instead of the `for` loop.
Thus you don't need to trim zero bits, because it will continue to loop only while there is at least one significant bit in a value.
Another advantage of this approach is that the result can be calculated using integer arithmetics only without using any kind of collections.

```
static int Reverse(int input)
{
    uint x = unchecked((uint)input);
    uint y = 0;
    while (x != 0)
    {
        y <<= 1;    // Shift accumulated result left
        y |= x & 1; // Set the least significant bit if it is set in the input value
        x >>= 1;    // Shift input value right
    }
    return unchecked((int)y);
}
```

Usage example:

```
int t = 0x103;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(t, 2));
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(Reverse(t), 2));
```

Result:

```
100000011
110000001
```

Comment: Adding more detail on why it works better would be better, but, that's about the same answer I would give.

Comment: For a negative `x` the loop seems to be infinite.

Answer (score 2):

[Dmitry's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/105639/16139) is probably better, but I'll provide another option.  If you wish to stick to using collections, you can replace the loops with LINQ to increase conciseness, readability, and safety.

```
public static IEnumerable<bool> ToBinary(this int n)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 32).Select(x => (n & (1 << x)) != 0);
}

public static int ToInt(this IEnumerable<bool> b)
{
    return b.Trim().Take(32).Select((x, i) => (x ? 1 : 0) << i).Sum();
}

private static IEnumerable<bool> Trim(this IEnumerable<bool> list)
{
    return list.SkipWhile(x => !x);
}
```